# Perl regex capture grouping

Tags: arrays, regex, perl

Is there a better way to write the below code using a regex capture grouping?

I'm looking to get the folder name immediately after Recordings.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my $path1 = '\\server1\Recordings\AU-AR-Online\Outbound\20160120\52031\52031-14-07-16.wav';
my $path2 = '\\server2\e$\Recordings\SU-AC-Online\Outbound\20160120\52031\52031-14-07-16.wav';

my @paths = ( $path1,$path2 );

foreach my $path (@paths) {
  # Split path into fields
  my @array = (split /\\/, $path);

  # Get index of Recordings
  my( $index )= grep { $array[$_] eq "Recordings" } 0..$#array;

  # Brand always follows Recordings
  print $array[$index+1];

 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, just replace the content of your loop with this:

```
my ($brand) = $path =~ m|\\Recordings\\([^\\]+)| or die "Not found";
print $brand;
```

Answer (score 1):

Capture the folder directly after `Recordings\`

```
my ($brand) = $path =~ m{ Recordings \\ ( [^\\] + ) }x )
```

Using the `x` modifier on the regex means whitespace is ignore, which can help make the regex more readable.

If the brand folder is always 5th-last, you could split the path and grab it by negative indexing.

```
my $brand = (split /\\/, $path)[-5];
```

But again, that only works if the brand is always 5th last. I don't know what your data set is.

Also, if your working with paths, there are many modules (such as `Path::Tiny`) that make it easier to get parent/child/absolute paths, basenames, etc.